# Website redirecting to a new address but not sending 3XX code

Tags: http, web-crawler, redirect

I am trying to crawl a website "http://www.daxontech.com"
If we type the above address into a web browser , the address automatically changes to http://www.benqmaterials.com/index.aspx

I tried using the response code to redirect my program to the above website, but response code is 200. Is there a way to retrieve the above address. I am using Jsoup for crawling.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The site you referenced uses a meta redirect which is done after headers are sent to the client.

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.BenQMaterials.com/index.aspx">
```

This is a fault with the website you are crawling and there is probably little you can do about it without parsing the html in the page for meta refresh tags (or other similar methods of redirection)

Comment: Thanks guys. I was able to locate the refresh attribute and then go to the content attribute to be accurate.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ curl "http://www.daxontech.com" -i
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/html
Last-Modified: Tue, 04 Jan 2011 08:47:58 GMT
Accept-Ranges: bytes
ETag: "61cc416ecabcb1:0"
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Tue, 07 Jan 2014 10:11:11 GMT
Content-Length: 304

<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=big5">
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.BenQMaterials.com/index.aspx">      
<title>BenQ Materials, the top four manufacturers of polarizer in the world.</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

It's not redirect but

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://www.BenQMaterials.com/index.aspx">
```

> The http-equiv attribute provides an HTTP header for the information/value of the content attribute.
>
> The http-equiv attribute can be used to simulate an HTTP response header.
>
> refresh:   Defines a time interval for the document to refresh itself.
>   Example:
>
> `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="300">`
>
> Note: The value "refresh" should be used carefully, as it takes the control of a page away from the user. Using "refresh" will cause a failure in W3C's Web Content Accessibility Guidelines.

So you can use such as xpath`("//meta[@http-equiv='refresh']");` or use regex find the string `<meta http-equiv="refresh"` to check the final location.

[reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_meta_http_equiv.asp)